# How to apply HTTP Patch in my REST API where the underlying resource is a custom properties file

Tags: rest, patch

I recently found out that JSON PATCH is only for applying PATCH where the underlying resource is JSON and the request body is something like this 
 { "op": "replace", "path": "/a/b/c", "value": 42 } for replace. 
Can I have something similar to this when the resource is a custom properties file instead of JSON? or is there any specification for general PATCH. The RFC for HTTP Patch just tells [description of changes] in the body like this.

```
PATCH /file.txt HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Content-Type: application/example
If-Match: "e0023aa4e"
Content-Length: 100

[description of changes]
```

Comment: JSON PATCH does not require the target resource to be JSON. Only the content of the request must be formatted as JSON. It is up to you to implement the operations as needed.

Comment: The Abstract from RFC https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6902 does say it is on a JSON document.

Comment: "This format is also potentially useful in other cases in which it is    necessary to make partial updates to a JSON document or to a data    structure that has similar constraints (i.e., they can be serialized    as an object or an array using the JSON grammar)."

Comment: Essentially, when they say "JSON document", they are not referring to the underlying resource representation at rest (this specification is not singularly targeted at NoSQL data stores). The JSON document could be a representation obtained from a call to a RESTful endpoint like `GET /customers/:id`... Essentially, you just need to form a representation of your properties file as a JSON document, which should be a simple task. An example representation for a properties file containing url, user, and password might be like: `{"url":"www.google.com","user":"jshmo","password":"1234"}`

Comment: Thanks. The quote was helpful.